# How do I use multiple browser instances at the same time in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a code that opens three same windows of website, and I need to do the same actions on them at the same time, is it possible? If yes, how can I make it? Btw, I am new to selenium, and programming at all, so sorry for a dumb question :d Thanks for any help.

Upd.
I've tried using something like this, and now actions are being made only at one window, what should I do?

```
browser_list = []

browser1 = webdriver.chrome()
browser2 = webdriver.chrome()
browser3 = webdriver.chrome()

browser_list.append(browser1)
browser_list.append(browser2)
browser_list.append(browser3)

for browser in browser_list:
    browser.get("link")

def akfqv():
    while True:
        browser1.find_element_by_xpath('')\
         .click()
        
def adkq():
    while True:
        browser2.find_element_by_xpath('')\
         .click()

def djqd():
    while True:
        browser3.find_element_by_xpath('')\
         .click()

thread1 = Thread(target=akfqv())
thread1 = Thread(target=adkq())
thread1 = Thread(target=djqd())

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
```

Comment: _I've tried using something like this, and now actions are being made only at one window_ In the code you shared here, the three functions are operating only on `browser1`. As an aside, what does _at the same time_ mean in this context?

Comment: @AMC Yep, my fault, in my real code three functions are operating on diferrent variables and still it applies click only at one, I meant that I want that click in here would be made on three windows at the same time, but in fact it works only at one of them

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], so we can see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

you can use list of webdriver and loop for each element

for example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
li=[]
li.append(webdriver.Chrome())
li.append(webdriver.Chrome())
li.append(webdriver.Chrome())
for i in li:
    i.get("https://google.com")
```

and if you not wait for complete task you can use asyncio
for more information about asyncio read [this article](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/)